# How can I run recursive find and replace operations on multiple files in parallel?

Tags: git, bash, sed, parallel-processing, find

I am attempting to replace text data in a git repository using the git filter-branch functionality.

I wrote a simple script to search for various terms and replace them. It was running extremely slow. I had multiple lines of BASH code executing to customize my search results and replacement operation. I know my code was not very efficient. I decided to go ahead and try just my first line which should be semi-efficient. It's still taking forever to walk through the code base.

**Is it possible to use BASH or another simple approach to search through my files and executed Find & Replace operations in parallel to speed things up?**

If not, are there any other suggestions on how to go about handling this better?

Here's the Git command I'm executing:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter "sh /home/kurtis/.bin/redact.sh || true" \
    -- --all
```

Here's the code my command is essentially executing:

```
find . -not -name "*.sql" -not -name "*.tsv" -not -name "*.class" \
    -type f -exec sed -i 's/01dPassw0rd\!/HIDDENPASSWORD/g' {} \;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

git filter-branch cannot process commits in parallel, becouse it needs to know hash (id) of parent commit to calculate current hash.

But you can speed up processing of each commit:

Your code executes sed for each file. That is very slow. Use this instead:

```
find . -not -name "*.sql" -not -name "*.tsv" -not -name "*.class" \
       -type f -print0 \
  | xargs -0 sed -i 's/01dPassw0rd\!/HIDDENPASSWORD/g'
```

This version does exactly the same as yours, but sed is executed with as many files (arguments) as possible. Find's "-print0" and xargs's "-0" means "separe filenames with zero byte". So there is no trouble when filename contains spaces, new lines, binary trash, etc.

Comment: That is definitely faster! I notice a pretty severe slow-down after Git hits approximately the 60th commit. I'm not sure if there's suddenly quite a bit more files added or not; I'll have to check. Thanks a lot for the great explanation too. Just to clarify on my end; I meant to parallel-ize the Search+Replace Operation (multiple files at a time), not the Git Updates (due to limitation you mentioned). Is this effectively the quickest/simplest way to maximize performance for this sort of a thing?

Comment: You could also run sed on changed files only instead of doing full scan. Something like: git diff --name-only ... | grep '.sql$' | xargs...

Comment: And to run sed in parallel, you can use "xargs -0 -P count ...".

Comment: How many commits do you have and for how long does this script run?

Comment: Over 2,000 Commits I believe. It gets progressively slower after around the 40th commit. I was unable to get the 'git diff ...' functionality to do anything (e.g. even display output so I can use it). I tried appending xargs with the '-P 4' parameter but I'm not sure if it's making a difference. I'm going to do another run on my Solid State in hopes it won't take hours. I don't mind it running over night; but I really want to check that it's properly doing its job before wasting too much processing time.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU Parallel you can parallelize on each CPU:

```
find . -not -name "*.sql" -not -name "*.tsv" -not -name "*.class" \
   -type f -print0 |
parallel -q -0 sed -i 's/01dPassw0rd\!/HIDDENPASSWORD/g'
```

Learn more: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Comment: I think this is a good recommendation. It's actually one route I started going down but didn't give it a shot as I ran out of time. Thanks!

Comment: in my benchmark with 1000 files, this was actually 2x slower than `find -exec`. i guess hard disks dont like random read/writes

Comment: @MilaNautikus Yep. The best advice to always measure.

Answer (score 1):

I found this problem interesting so I played with it a little and I share this partly working script. My original approach was a bit wrong but it may be fast(er).

I tried to improve the performance by searching for modified files in every commit where the modification contains the string you want to replace with `git log -Sstring`. But I forgot if I change only those then the modification will appear in the next commit so I had to run the script several times, but it doesn't check all the files just the modifications so it may be faster to run this multiple times then your version, but I'm not sure how much time does the filter-branch takes if does nothing.

You may be able to use parts of it, maybe get all file names first with `git log -S...`. And you can improve it by using `xargs` before `sed` instead of the `for` loop, but while developing I like this form better. I don't know how to discover parents properly that's why I did it this way and had to handle the initial commit case separately.

Anyway I'm here to learn too so if you find a good way to deal with this problem please share :)

```
#!/bin/bash

commit=$1
pattern=$2
replace=$3

function replaceall() {
  for f in `git log -S$pattern --pretty="format:" --name-only $1 | egrep -v '.sql$|.class$|.tsv$'`; do
    echo "FILE $f"
    sed -i "s/$pattern/$replace/g" $f
  done
}

parents=`git log --pretty=%P -n 1 $commit`
if test -z "$parents"; then
  echo "ROOT"
  replaceall $commit
else
  for p in $parents; do
    echo "PARENT $p"
    replaceall $p..$commit
  done
fi
```

Usage: `git filter-branch -f --tree-filter '/path/to/script.sh $commit 01dPassw0rd\! HIDDENPASSWORD' -- --all`

*I think the script shouldn't be in your git working directory because tree-filter adds everything it found while rewriting, but I'm not sure about this.*

Answer (score 1):

You want the [BFG Repo-Cleaner](http://rtyley.github.com/bfg-repo-cleaner/), a faster, simpler alternative to `git-filter-branch` that runs in the JVM and is explicitly designed for removing private data from Git repos. It's multi-threaded and optimised for precisely the task you're describing. It's typically 10-50x times faster than `git-filter-branch` - the bigger your repo, the faster it is.

Download the Java jar, create a `private.txt` file listing the passwords, etc, that you want to remove (one entry per line) and then run this command:

```
$ java -jar bfg.jar  --replace-text private.txt  my-repo.git
```

All files under a threshold size (1MB by default) in your repo's history will be scanned, and any matching string (that isn't in your *latest* commit) will be replaced with the string "***REMOVED***". You can then use `git gc` to clean away the dead data:

```
$ git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

Comment: This sounds perfect. I've already went ahead and converted the repo but noticed there's a few more keywords I should have hidden. I'll give this a try and report back with my results (and possibly a checkmark). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

some benchmarks for recursive text replace ([source](https://github.com/milahu/sed-recursive-benchmark))

```
0.131411 sec  find-xargs-sd.sh

0.323906 sec  find-xargsparallel-sed.sh
0.326623 sec  find-xargs-sed.sh
0.397934 sec  find-xargs-perl.sh

4.53739 sec  find-exec-sed.sh

10.3247 sec  parallel-sed.sh
```